# AEM 6.0 to 6.3 Upgrade - Authentication issue with post servlet (web service)

Tags: authentication, csrf, aem, sling

I am having a weird issue and not sure how to resolve it! We are in the process of upgrading from AEM 6.0 to 6.3. In 6.3 we have created several web services to support almost all the UI features like Upload Asset, Get Asset, Lock/Unlock Asset etc. I am testing the same services from my local Eclipse client and Chrome Postman REST client.

Basically during testing, I am providing my user id as "AUTH_USER" header key. AEM 6.0 authenticates me using SlingAuthenticator and my ID is available as principal in the servlet code (request.getUserPrincipal()).

In case of 6.3, the web service invocation works fine first time. But then it fails to authenticate my ID for next 1 hour or so. After that period, it again works one time and so on. Following is the message I get in error.log during that "period"

> 16.06.2017 14:52:09.420 *INFO* [qtp1065074294-107] org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator handleLoginFailure:
>   Unable to authenticate apaldhik: Login Failure: all modules ignored

As per Adobe support recommendation, I also added the CSRF-Token but that doesn't help (it does work without CSRF token once every hour !).

Any help/pointers are greatly appreciated.

6/23/17:

So I still need to get exact details in terms of how our application is doing the authentication with AUTH_USER (I am new to this team). The way it works is, if I am connecting via virtual IP to a cluster of Authors then I need to generated an OAM (oracle access manager) token using my credentials.

However if I connect to a single author then "AUTH_USER" is works fine. The Author is synced with Cisco's LDAP and it can authenticate that I am a valid user. It works fine with the existing 6.0 instance, also as I mentioned it works once in every hour or so with 6.3 (sounds very weird!).

I was able to get the error log at the debug level for success and failure scenarios. I can see that in case of success, Sling Quartz scheduler connects with the LDAP for my user ID and gets the details. However in case of failure it doesn't connect to LDAP.

I am wondering if there is some interval set for this LDAP connector.

Thanks
- Atul

Comment: I assume you are running this webservice on author based on the use case. What I do not get is why you would use the `AUTH_USER` header? Usually, AEM author does use "Basic Authentication". So all you have to do in your webservice client is to use Basic Authentication. If the Basic Authentication credentials are ok the request is routed to the servlet (I guess you use a servlet) and the rest should be working just fine.

Comment: If you change your error logging to TRACE level, you will see some more information on why the authentication failed. Apply TRACE on `org.apache.sling.auth.core` namespace and dump the logs for more info.